# Tomcat Connection Pool under WEB-INF/context.xml or TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, tomcat, connection-pooling

This is the first time I'm trying to set up a connection pool in tomcat (version 8), and I'm kind of confused. It seems that I have 2 options available to me, 1) I can add something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource for oracle -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="DB_USERNAME" 
              password="DB_PASSWORD"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:1525:dbname"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4" />
</Context>
```

In a file called 'context.xml' in my projects WEB-INF folder. **OR**, 2) I can add something like this:

```
<Context path="/dbcp" docBase="dbcp" debug="5"
reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="30" maxActive="100"
   maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="kunal"
   password="java_facier"
   driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbcptest"/>

</Context>
```

in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/sever.xml and then add this:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description> DB Connection Pooling</description>
    <res-ref-name> jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type> javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth> Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

to my WEB-INF/web.xml file in my project...

If I'm correct in both instances here, which one is better to use? Also where would I put my database vendors jdbc-driver?

Comment: If only one web app will use, then I can not see why you would want to put it in server.xml.  The less you mess around with this the better.

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat, that does make sense. Where would I put my DB vendor's JDBC-driver then? If I use maven I could just specify it in my pom.xml?

Comment: personally I would go for WEB-INF/lib using maven of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put JDBC libraries to $tomcat/lib folder so that webapp reloads don't touch it. I have found this the best common rule and even an official [Apache Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Preventing_database_connection_pool_leaks) instructs  $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder so please follow their wisdom.

**$tomcat/webapps/mywebapp/META-INF/context.xml**
This provides you an application level pool. You having two or more webapps connecting to a same database each have own pool. It means they obye own private max-limit and such meters. Distributing and installing mywebapp.war file is easy, this is a self-contained application.

**$tomcat/conf/server.xml**
This provides a global pool where two or more webapps share same max-limit and such meters. If you must control the overall number of connections opened to the db engine this is where you should put jdbc settings. Tomcat admin must put this setting in place before deploying a webapp.

edit: Oh I see you have put jdbc settings inside the `<Context>` element in server.xml file. Well, in that case I think its still a webapp-private pool. If you need global pool you add it inside `<GlobalNamingResources>` element at the top of xml file.

Comment: I don't feel religious about this but, I prefer WEB-INF/lib as I am oft to forget to deploy jars in $tomcat/lib and also sometimes face version issues if diff webapps use diff version of the DB

Answer (score 1):

Either approach has it pros and cons :
  1. Application level packaging creates App local connection pools.
  2. Independent from Tomcat's setup
but,
  Application on release requires environment specific releases.

While, if tomcat maintains connection pool then app only depends on "Registered Name" and single package can be distributed for all environments.

> Just to summarize, App level packaging is **developer centric** whereas Tomcat-maintained connection pools are **Operational friendly**.